# Can we make a cpp application as HA using keepalived?

Tags: linux, networking, high-availability, keep-alive, failover

I have an application written in c++. I am running this application in 2 different servers with same instance id. So with linux HA, i can able to send the calls to master server. Once master server goes down, backup server starts recieving the calls.
Can we do samething using keepalived instead of linux HA?

Answer (score 0):

I must highlight that I don't know much about Linux HA but why not use a proxy tool like HAProxy? it can handle and balance your instances....

Or if you want your instances to always be up, you can supervise them using tools like supervisor...

I must say that I don't really understand the question but hope that my answer is at least in the zone...

Comment: I have 2 servers running the same application, but the application in master server receives the calls. Once the application goes down in master, slave becomes master and receives the calls. This is being done by linux HA currently in my environment. Once state changes, a script will update the stateful file with the status MASTER or SLAVE, based on that status my application decides whether to take calls or not.
So, now i want to do the same thing using keepalived since i heard configurations in keepalived are much easier than LinuxHA.
Could any one help me to configure keepalived?

Comment: I have done those changes with keepalived. I could achieve High Availability using keepalived. Thanks Adrian.